# Embedded YouTube in iOS Safari just spins

Tags: ios5, youtube-api

I have a number of very small pages which basically loads a video for use on mobile browsers. In the latest iOS (5.1.1) the video player loads, but then just spins. The video can be played by clicking on the video, but since it looks like it's still loading, people may not do that. Works everywhere else.

I'm using the youtube api code

This is a test version of the page.
http://bit.ly/S2KuN1

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Celebrity's Caribbean Shore Excursions</title>
<link href="http://www.celebritycruises.com/css/min/global.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://media.celebritycruises.com/celebrity/content/en_US/css/m_video.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// create youtube player
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      videoId: 'PH-m591p4xg',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="m_video.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="video_page">
<div class="logo"><a href="http://m.celebritycruises.com/m/home.do"><img src="http://media.celebritycruises.com/celebrity/content/en_US/images/cel_misc/logo.jpg" alt="Celebrity Mobile" width="259" height="55" border="0"></a></div>
<div id="player"></div>
<div class="visit">
<p>Now visit Celebrity Cruises' official mobile website.</p>
<p><a class="ccButton large" target="_self" href="http://m.celebritycruises.com/m/home.do"> <span class="text">Explore</span> <span class="pointer"> </span> </a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the js for the page

// JavaScript Document

```
// autoplay video
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.pauseVideo();
}

// when video ends
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {
        window.location = "http://m.celebritycruises.com/m/home.do";
    }
}

//style Blackberry
window.onload = function() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if (ua.indexOf("BlackBerry") != -1 ) {
        document.getElementById("video_page").className = "bb";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to solve it.

I changed

```
event.target.pauseVideo();
```

to

```
event.target.stopVideo();
```

I don't know what the issue is, but iOS 5.1.1 never seems to finish autoloading. Using the stopVideo() command from the YouTube api stops the process and the play button appears. Once clicked, it loads normally.